# MongoDB change document position after update

Tags: php, mongodb

Actually I am doing project using mongodb. after I update record and find all records, it change the document position. so how I avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'natural' (i.e. unsorted) order of docs in a collection can change as updates are made so if you want a specific order to the docs returned from a query you need to include a sort object in your query.